# JSONP script returning MIME Type error

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Hello I'm currently working on a script that must extract information from a third party feed which returns a json file. I am not able to use CORS since I do not have server access, so based on desk research I was informed to use JSONP. I am able to see the callback (response) in chrome network's tab but I can't read the file in the chrome log. The point is that when I execute the following code I get the Error Message below. I can't turn off mime type checking. I've tried to have a look on other questions but couldn't find anything similar.
What should be done?

"Refused to execute script from 'https://siteurl.com/json=jsonp&callback=jQuery321030035432758818903_1501098778362&_=1501098778363' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. "

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'siteurl.com/json?callback=jsonp',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: false
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept" : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
            },
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, errorText) {
                console.log('Error ' + xhr.responseText);
            }
        }); 
</script>
```

Take a look at the network tab:

[Network tab view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jn2vg.png)

Comment: Are you sure the server supports responding with jsonp? When you preview the response in the network tab is there `jQuery321030035432758818903_1501098778362(` before the actual json?

Comment: `"Content-Type": "application/javascript; charset=utf-8"` — This makes no sense. You are making a GET request. There is no request body to describe the content type of.

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"` — This makes no sense. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a **response** header, not a request header.

Comment: @yuriy636 yes, take a look at the link in the end of the question that I have just included.

Comment: @Colpachi well that is not JSONP, the server is responding with JSON, that's why the MIME mismatches.

Comment: @yuriy636 I see. So how could I solve this? I cant retrieve a JSON directly because the server has CORS configuration active, so I have used JSONP. 
As I am using JSONP and the server response is a JSON file, how could I read it in the console? Do you have any guess?

Comment: @Colpachi Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

JSONP is not JSON! JSONP is a **JavaScript program** consisting of a function call with one argument.

The correct Content-Type is `application/javascript`.

---

> I am not able to use CORS since I do not have server access, so based on desk research I was informed to use JSONP.

You can only use JSONP if the site provides JSONP. (These days they should use CORS instead, it is better in every way). Just slapping `callback` in a query string will not magically force a site to provide JSONP and break the same origin policy for you. The site has to explicitly expose the data to other sites.

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 — That is what line 2 of this answer says.

Comment: What I can't understand is why then the server is sending the callback with the JSON file? The file is already in the brownser, it's just a matter of reading it in the console.

Comment: @Colpachi — "What I can't understand is why then the server is sending the callback with the JSON file? " — Is it? You haven't shown the response or provided a URL which works. Possibly it is simply a bug, in which case the problem still needs to be fixed on the server.

Comment: @Colpachi — "The file is already in the brownser, it's just a matter of reading it in the console." — See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068 
 specifically the section "Why the Same Origin Policy only applies to JavaScript in a web page"

Comment: @Colpachi — That is not a JSONP response. That is JSON. See the last paragraph of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with Content-Type.

> **Content-Type** : `application/json` is correct for JSON but its not for JSONP.
>
> **Content-Type** : `application/javascript` is for JSONP.

Please check this : [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type)

Comment: I'm afraid is not because when I change to application/javascript the error message is the same:

"Refused to execute script from 'https://siteurl.com/json=jsonp&callback=jQuery321030035432758818903_1501098778362&_=1501098778363' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. "